# ggplot2 Warning while ploting barplot : Use of `train[[i]]` is discouraged. Use `.data[[i]]` instead

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-science, bar-chart

I tried to plot some barplot using the famous Kaggle challenge [Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) and ggplot2. My goal is to get barplot by giving to ggplot2 only the y-values as input (so that it would count them automatically). I succeeded using this code (where train is the Titanic trainset available on Kaggle) :

```
index_qualitative_features #= [4  5  9 11 12]
i = index_qualitative_features[2] #= 5
x_title = colnames(train)[i] #= "Sex"

ggplot(data=train, aes(train[[i]])) + 
    geom_bar(width=0.3) + 
    xlab(x_title) + ylab(y_title) + 
    theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12), 
          axis.title.x = element_text(size=13.5, face="bold"), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(size=13.5, face="bold"))
```

But I got this Warning :
`` Warning: Use of `train[[i]]` is discouraged. Use `.data[[i]]` instead. ``

I do not understand by what I should replace `train[[i]]` to get rid of that warning, and what `.data[[i]]` means (I tried to write `.data[[i]]` instead but it didn't even execute).

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: The `aes()` function works through non-strandard evaluation, so it should receive symbols of column names, e.g. `aes(x = my_x_variable, y = my_y_variable)`. The `.data[[i]]` method is (one of the) suggested interface(s) to use `aes()` programmatically, as explained in [this vignette](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function-1). I'm not sure what you're attempting to achieve with `aes(train[[i]])`, could you explain a bit more? It would be helpful to turn your code into a reproducible example.

Comment: @teunbrand Thank you, thanks to the vignette I understood that the i in `.data[[i]]` is a string (the name of the column we want), which I didn't grasp before. In fact, I tried to plot several barplot in a for loop, that is why I need numerical index of the columns of the dataset (which is why I wrote `aes(train[[i]])`). But I just wrote `aes(.data[[feature_name]])` instead where `feature_name = colnames(train)[i]` (the for loop `being for(i in index_qualitative_features)`). My problem is solved.